# Updating multiple rows with CASE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax

I can't figure this out, there are many examples here on stack overflow but there are differences in each one, and they are all giving the same problem.

I've got a list of 80 "slides" which have a column named "order". Order is a number, currently ranging from 0 to 79.

If we delete a slide, we need to adjust the slides following that one, which I've already worked out the algorithm for.

Here is the result of the algorithm:

```
UPDATE cms_slides SET order = 
    CASE order
        WHEN 68 THEN 67
        WHEN 69 THEN 68
    END CASE
WHERE order BETWEEN 68 AND 69
```

This is current code is based on Soulmerge's solution here: [Updating display order of multiple MySQL rows in one or very few queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748720/updating-display-order-of-multiple-mysql-rows-in-one-or-very-few-queries)

The column "order" does in fact reside in "cms_slides", and the values 1 through 69 all exist under "order".

THe error message is the typical: *ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual...*

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code? I have tried many variations but none work, it's probably something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL you should use backticks around it and you do not need the `END CASE` just use `END`:

```
UPDATE cms_slides SET `order` = 
    CASE `order`
        WHEN 68 THEN 67
        WHEN 69 THEN 68
    END 
WHERE `order` BETWEEN 68 AND 69
```

Comment: Ah, should have realized that, I use the ORDER keyword in another query on the same script. Works fine now though, thanks!